# Адаптивность элементов при изменении ширины родителя?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive

Имеются, к примеру, бутстрап навигации (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/). Все они адаптивные.

Если поместить каждый элемент в отдельный див .demo, то при изменении width этого дива адаптивность не срабатывает. Это связано с тем, что медиа запросы смотрят на ширину, высоту и пр. именно экрана, а не родителя-элемента.

Возможно как-нибудь с помощью js сделать чтобы @media запросы для дочерних элементов дива .demo ориентировались именно на параметры своего родителя .demo?

Вариант с iframe не подходит

Comment: Единственное что пришло в голову - айфрейм, но он не подходит. Пробовал гуглить проблему, ничего похожего не находил. Стандартными средствами не решить, вот и спрашиваю, может ли js помочь

Comment: а зачем такой головняк ? если используете bs то используйте его со всеми его 'кишками'

Comment: Поставили задачу, сделать возможность смотреть как будет смотреться тот или иной элемент на разных разрешениях экрана. Сделал кнопки «телефон», «планшет», «пк», которые меняют ширину дива, а вот с адаптивностью проблему никак решить не могу

Comment: Вариант с функцией javascript window.open() рассматривали? там можно открыть документ в отдельном окне, с определенными размерами.

Comment: Лень, рулит этим миром.... Всегда говорил, что ***`BS`*** - это зло...

Comment: @NArts, я не могу понять, с чего вдруг `Это связано с тем, что медиа запросы смотрят на ширину, высоту и пр. именно экрана, а не родителя-элемента.` ???? Это что значит? приведи пример

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914831/make-children-css-attributes-depend-on-parent-element-size-like-media-queries-d Мне кажется что это именно то, что Вы ищите.